# NeoVim make terminal window automatically close when program exits

Tags: neovim

The vim version has a [++close](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#terminal-close) option that automatically closes the terminal when the job terminates, but since the NeoVim terminal came first it doesn't have that feature.

I need this because i am trying to run programs directly from vim, but i regularly make
curses applications which the popup window you get from `:!python %` can't handle, so i need the terminal window.

I am using NeoVim on arch linux if that's relevant.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using an `autocmd` on the `TermClose` event. From the neovim manual (`:help terminal`):

```
autocmd TermClose * if !v:event.status | exe 'bdelete! '..expand('<abuf>') | endif
```

I didn't care about the exit status, so for my personal configuration I simplified it to

```
autocmd TermClose * execute 'close!'
```

Finally, since I am using lua in `~/.config/nvim/init.lua` with neovim, I translated it to lua as follows:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("TermClose", {
    callback = function()
       vim.cmd("close")
    end
})
```

Comment: It may make more sense in some cases to use `bdelete` instead of `close`.